# How to map json object for elasticsearch

Tags: json, database, elasticsearch, mapping

I'm asking this because the Elasticsearch queries looks like tend to work only with arrays; including arrays filled with objects i.e. `[object]`. And the documentation about this use case it's unclear.

I want to add something like:

```
{
    "word1": 1,
    "word2": 2,
    "word3": 3,
    "word4": 4 
}
```

How is the mapping syntax for elasticsearch? Also, it'll have a good performance or it's better to go for `[object]`?

Comment: Do you mean to insert the above json values into a single object? @Bursos

Comment: More or less, I update with the answer ;) Thanks for reply @kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Pretty simple:

The mapping:

```
"mapping": {
  "type": {
    "properties": {
      "jsonHere": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Anyway, after a few tests looks like the performance of `[object]` is better. But I cannot assure that's right. I should make more tests. What's clear is that the map above is correct.